# Python: How to insert return inside if __name__ == main?

Tags: python, function, return

This gives error:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    box = Myfunc()
    box.do(1)
    if box.loop() <> Drh.DrhOk:
        return 
    else:
      ...
      ...
```

SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

How do I return `if __name__=="__main__":` block?

Comment: The error is self descriptive. You are calling return outside a function.

Comment: If you have an `else:` block, why do you need to return at all?

Comment: Side note: Using `<>` instead `!=` is deprecated.  Use the latter.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters because box.loop() may have an invalid value. Then funtion must return.

Comment: @alwbtc: But it *is not a function*. It is the piece of code that is run when this is the main module instead. There is nothing to return *to*; if everything else is in the `else:` suite, the code naturally will come to the end and *nothing else will happen*. You could use `sys.exit()`, or wrap this in a `main()` function, but in the end, neither of this will make a difference to what Python actually executes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't.  Your `__main__` block should always read:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Putting your code inside a `main()` function ensures that it is testable.

Comment: It would be more correct to say `allows it to be testable`, `ensures` implies that there's no way you could write `main()` to be untestable.

Answer (score 9):

You don't want to return, you probably want to stop the execution. Use [sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)